# Want to iterate specific code through invalid input array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have one java class in which there are getters and setters..

I want to iterate few characters in each and every field, once at a time..

```
Test test = new Test();
test.get().getUserDetails().setEmail(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "@testing.com");
        test.get().getUserDetails().getMobilePhone().setCountryCode("+91");
        test.get().getUserDetails().getMobilePhone().setPhoneNumber("997464" + randomNum);
```

I have pair of 3 special characters `String invalidcharacters[] = {"!@&*"," ","^^^","null:};`

I want to iterate 1 special characters in only 1 setters at a time.. i.e; I want to check special characters validation for Email and rest fields would be same.. Same goes with other fields. I want to do same with rest 2 special characters as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the characters of each `string` within the array?Also, why would you have `null` inside the array?

Comment: Yes, i.e; for 1 special character string, say "^^^", I want this to be inserted firstly in 1 setter(email) and then in second iteration some another setter(countrycode) etc. Would like to do same with all sp char strings in array.

Comment: changed null to "null" @OusmaneMahyDiaw, thanks for that.

Comment: Can be considered as a string.. Say "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" in arrays.

Comment: yes, that's true, but how to insert it in only 1 setters, leaving all other untouched and in next iteration, same string with other setters?